# Oracle certification

Tags: oracle

I am a 3 year experienced software developer with fairly good TSQL knowledge in SQL Server. I am looking for expanding skill to  Oracle also. What all things I should learn to say confidently thaty 'I know Oracle'?

Any free online certification available?

Pease share your thoughts..

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589983/should-i-do-mcts-exam-in-sql-server-or-net-programming

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about certification advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to expand your Oracle application development skills (and not your DBA skills) you could look at gaining the [1Z0-047 Oracle Database SQL Expert](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=41&p_org_id=1001&lang=US&p_exam_id=1Z0_047) certification. A good study guide for this is [OCA Oracle Database SQL Expert Exam Guide: Exam 1Z0-047](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071614214). I used this in combination with the Oracle 11g SQL Reference to pass 1Z0-047.

Working with Oracle in production for a couple of years will also help you to expand your Oracle skills.

As an introduction to essential Oracle concepts and techniques have a look at [Expert Oracle Database Architecture: 9i and 10g Programming Techniques and Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595300) by Tom Kyte.

Answer (score 2):

As to "free online certifications", I'd not bother with those (if any).
They have no value, are impossible to verify that the person claiming to hold them actually does and are not recognised by pretty much anyone.

At best they could serve as practice for the real exams, at worst they'll give you a bad impression about your skills (as they may well have bad questions requiring factually incorrect answers).